# Telegram TypeError: send_message() got multiple values for argument 'parse_mode'

Tags: python, telebot

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, open(name + '.gif', 'rb'), link,parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 0):

bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(name + '.gif', 'rb'), link,parse_mode='HTML')